# Trigger filter on POCO property

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I'm trying to create a multi step process handled by a QueueTrigger per Step.  How can I filter on the 'state' property of a QueueMessage object without having a Queue per state?
Msg is of type:

```
public partial class TaskType{
    string BlobPathToProcess {get; set;}
    int State {get; set;}
}


 public static void Task(
     [QueueTrigger(queueName: "taskq")] TaskType msg
     TextWriter log,
     IBinder binder)
{
     //currently I use a switch statement on (TaskType.State == 1)
```

So not:

```
[QueueTrigger(queueName: "taskqstate1")] TaskType msg

[QueueTrigger(queueName: "taskqstate2")] TaskType msg
```

etc.

Maybe like [@pranav-rastogi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439326/pranav-rastogi) says about the [Singleton attribute](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/b1fb20b0edf0530d62127d6dd9f50cc9345ca7b6/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/SingletonAttribute.cs) on [MSDN Ch9 cloud cover at min 24](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-183-Azure-WebJobs-Update-with-Pranav-Rastogi)

```
[Singleton(@"{Region}\{Zone}"]
public static void Task([QueueTrigger(singleto-test")] WorkItem workItem, ...
```

Where {Region} and {Zone} are properties from the 'workItem' object.

More like:

```
[PocoFilter(PocoProperty="{State}", PocoValue="1"]
public static void Task1([QueueTrigger(queueName: "taskq")] TaskType msg ...

[PocoFilter(PocoProperty="{State}", PocoValue="2"]
public static void Task2([QueueTrigger(queueName: "taskq")] TaskType msg ...
```

Comment: to create worflow, you can use servicebus topic and create subscription with sqlfilter. I ll post an answer tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Azure Queue does not have a messaging filtering feature.

If you move to Azure Service Bus topics and subscriptions, you will be able to filter based on message properties.

to create a topic and subscriptions you can have a look at this article :

- [How to use Service Bus topics and subscriptions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/)

So let says, you've created

- A topic with name "MyTestTopic"
- A subscription with name "MySubscription1" and with a [SqlFilter](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/#create-a-subscription) "Status = 1"

  - Only messages sent to the topic with a property Status = 1 will be routed to this subscription.
- A subscription with name "MySubscription2" and with a SqlFilter "Status = 2"

  - Only messages sent to the topic with a property Status = 2 will be routed to this subscription.

In you webjob, you can have twos function that looks like that:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage1(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("MyTestTopic", "MySubscription1")] BrokeredMessage incomingMessage,
    ServiceBus("MyTestTopic")] out BrokeredMessage outputMessage)
{
    // Status should be 1
    Console.Out.WriteLine(incomingMessage.Properties["Status"]);

    // Get your poco
    var myPoco = incomingMessage.GetBody<TaskType>();

   //Process your message ...
   ....

   // clone the message
   outputMessage = incomingMessage.Clone();

   // Set the status to 2
   outputMessage.Properties["Status"] = 2
}

public static void ProcessQueueMessage2(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("MyTestTopic", "MySubscription2")] BrokeredMessage incomingMessage)
{
    // Status should be 2
    Console.Out.WriteLine(incomingMessage.Properties["Status"]);

    // Do what you need
}
```

In the fisrt method, we use a ServiceBusTriggerAttribute to listen for messages coming to the subscription 1 and a ServiceBusAttribute to send a message to the topic.

When you want to send a message, just don't forget to set the "Status" property of the BrokeredMessage .

Comment: Is the SqlFilter correct? You say: "Status = 2 -> Only messages sent to the topic with a property Status == 1". Should it be "Status ==2"? Are you suggesting upgrading my Q to use ServiceBus?